# Oracle RESULT_CACHE hint

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, caching

Respective all!

Can I expect from v$result_cache_objects , that when I have my query with RESULT_CACHE hint included, I should see a non-zero value in row_count column of v$result_cache_objects for my query?

Like this:

```
Select /*+ RESULT_CACHE*/ order_id, order_name 
from orders
```

i would like to issue

```
select row_count from v$cache_memory_objects 
  where cache_id = <cache id of my query>
```

and see a non-zero value for row_count.

Environment:
Oracle 18c XE

Params:

```
result_cache_mode               MANUAL
result_cache_max_size           8060928
result_cache_max_result         5
result_cache_remote_expiration  0
```

I think that row_count equal to non-zero is very significant
to make me believe that RESULT_CACHE is works.
If you have another criterias  to make developer believe that
RESULT_CACHE is works , please point me.

Thanks in advance,
Andrew.

Comment: your assumption is good, checkout my article on the subject for more details: https://www.dba-scripts.com/articles/oracle-internals/result-cache/

Answer (score 1):

Well the first thing to check in [v$result_cache_objects](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/refrn/V-RESULT_CACHE_OBJECTS.html#GUID-2DA2EDEA-8B1D-42E6-A293-663B3124AAFD) is the `STATUS` is must be `Published` to be able to use the cached result.

The `ROW_COUNT` is greater than zero, but is not as interesting, simple saying the cached result has N rows.

The more relevant is the column `SCAN_COUNT` giving the number of times the cached result was used.

A total overview of the cache usage may be obtained in the view [v$result_cache_statistics](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/refrn/V-RESULT_CACHE_STATISTICS.html#GUID-9E89646B-102D-4211-A181-DDF96F809289)
providing following measures (above other information):

```
Create Count Success
Find Count
Invalidation Count
```

Basically while using a *cache* you are trying to see the `Find Count` (i.e. using the cached result) much higher than the `Create Count Success` (i.e. query performed and the result was cached)

**but...**

the generall problem with the `RESULT_CACHE` in Oracle (and this is the reason why it was introduced so late and is only marginaly used) is that

- performant queries work *fine even without cache* and sometimes when *cached* need *more elapsed time* to complete due to internal overhead of the cache.
- non-performant queries *profit from the cache*, but the question appears immediately, why the application is repeatedly sending the *identical* query...

Comment: Thank you, Marmite!

Comment: well, if you find the answer usefull, you may also upvote and/or accept;) @AndrewKlimov and appologise for my skeptical view, but I'm convinced, that contrary to e.g. Hibernate where the *caches* are considered important, down on the RDBMS it is a *bit* of overkill.